Google Play purchases.subscriptionsv2.revoke API is giving me "The subscription is not eligible for prorated refund." error
I'm implementing a new refund feature using the purchases.subscriptionsv2.revoke API instead of the purchases.subscription.revoke I was using before. I'm trying to use the 'Prorate refunds' feature in purchases.subscriptionsv2.revoke to automatically refund prorate recurring payments.
But when I test it, I get an error like this for both test payment / real payment.
First, I issued a test / real payment and then tried to revoke it.
request params:
{
    "method": "POST",
    "url": "https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/<my_package_name>/purchases/subscriptionsv2/tokens/<my_purchase_token>:revoke?access_token=<my_access_token>",
    "json": true,
    "body": {
        "revocationContext": {
            "proratedRefund": {}
        }
    }
}

(part of) results:
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "The subscription is not eligible for prorated refund.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The subscription is not eligible for prorated refund.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "failedPrecondition"
            }
        ],
        "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
    }
}

Which subscriptions are eligible for prorated refunds? I'm having trouble troubleshooting this as I've searched with the relevant error messages and nothing comes up. It doesn't seem there's an option that can set 'prorated refund eligible' subscription on Google Play Console. Please help!

According to Google's support, an error is returned when there is no actual amount to be partially refunded.
For example:

When tried prorated refund on a test payment: Since there was no real payement, no actual amount to be refunded, an error occurs.
When tried prorated refund immediately after making a real payment: There is no amount to be refunded because no usage has occurred yet. An error is returned.
When tried prorated refund on the last day of the subscription after making a real payment: In this case, there is no amount to be refunded. An error is returned.

When testing prorated refund before app launch, if you make a real payment and wait for a short period (at least 2-3 minutes) before attempting a prorated refund, you should not encounter an error.
Hope this helps someone.
